# React JS app not preserving linebreaks in transliteration output

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I developed a ReactJS app that transliterates text input. The app is mostly functioning as intended, but there's a problem with how line breaks in the input are being handled. Specifically, when the input value is processed for transliteration and then displayed as output, the line breaks are not being respected. Instead, the transliterated words on each line are being connected to the last word of the previous line, resulting in a jumbled output.

Both text areas need to be editable so it limits some of the solutions I have found online:

**Component Code Snippets
**

```
  const handleInputChange = useCallback(async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    const lowercasedValue = value.toLowerCase();
    setInputValue(value);
    setInputValueLowercase(lowercasedValue);
    const response = await fetch(`/api/transliterate?value=${lowercasedValue}&from=latin&to=georgian`);
    const { result } = await response.json();
    setOutputValue(result);
  }, []);

  const handleOutputChange = useCallback(async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setOutputValue(value);
    const response = await fetch(`/api/transliterate?value=${value}&from=georgian&to=latin`);
    const { result } = await response.json();
    setInputValue(result);
  }, []);
```

```
<textarea ref={inputRef} type="text" id="input" className='english-font' style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }} value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange} />


<textarea ref={outputRef} id='output' className='georgian-font' style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }} value={outputValue} onChange={handleOutputChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary workaround while I look for a cleaner solution. For now, I have modified:

```
  const handleInputChange = useCallback(async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    const lowercasedValue = value.toLowerCase();
    setInputValue(value);
    setInputValueLowercase(lowercasedValue);
    const response = await fetch(`/api/transliterate?value=${lowercasedValue}&from=latin&to=georgian`);
    const { result } = await response.json();
    setOutputValue(result);
  }, []);

  const handleOutputChange = useCallback(async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setOutputValue(value);
    const response = await fetch(`/api/transliterate?value=${value}&from=georgian&to=latin`);
    const { result } = await response.json();
    setInputValue(result);
  }, []);
```

to

```
  const handleInputChange = useCallback(async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    const lowercasedValue = value.toLowerCase().replace(/\n/g, '<@@@>');
    setInputValue(value);
    setInputValueLowercase(lowercasedValue);
    const response = await fetch(`/api/transliterate?value=${lowercasedValue}&from=latin&to=georgian`);
    const { result } = await response.json();
    setOutputValue(result.replace(/<@@@>/g, '\n'));
  }, []);
  
  const handleOutputChange = useCallback(async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    const linebreakValue = value.replace(/\n/g, '<@@@>');
    setOutputValue(value);
    const response = await fetch(`/api/transliterate?value=${linebreakValue}&from=georgian&to=latin`);
    const { result } = await response.json();
    setInputValue(result.replace(/<@@@>/g, '\n'));
  }, []);
```

Essentially this will replace the line breaks from the both text areas to <@@@> before its sent to the logic and the result will replace the <@@@> with \n again before displaying them.